# UITableView Cells background color NOT changing?

Tags: ios, uitableview, storyboard

I have a UITableView set up in two storyboards - one for iPhone and one for iPad.

I have set it up in the iPhone storyboard such that the cells have a clear background and so a background image shows through - this works perfectly fine.

HOWEVER, when I copy this view in to the iPad storyboard, for some reason the table cells have a white background even though all the settings are the same (clear colour still set in the builder).

What could be the reason for this?

EDIT - I've looked at this further and if I change the colour of a row to anything, it won't change - for some reason it remains white :/

Comment: Are the cells definitely not ticked as opaque?

Comment: It was ticked (even in the iPhone one) but unticking it makes no difference. I don't know if this is just a bug with the Simulator as everything is the same and it views fine on the iPhone storyboard

Comment: does it work if you programmatically set the background color?

Comment: I haven't tried this, any simple way to apply the code rather than adding all the Table stuff to the class? Also, I don't know how it would make a difference if it's already working fine in the iPhone?

Answer (score 3):

Appears to be a known issue with this, and the fix is by adding the following to the .m file for your class:

```
   - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have  to set the backgroundColor of the cell's contentView to your color

```
cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor yourcolor];
```

Answer (score 0):

From iOS 7, UITableViewCell have a default white background.

Set: `cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];`
and eventually : `cell.contentView.backgroundView = nil;`

And verifiy also your:
`tableview.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
tableview.backgroundView = nil;`

Answer (score 0):

```
extension UITableViewCell {
    func setTransparent() {
        let bgView: UIView = UIView()
        bgView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        self.backgroundView = bgView
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        self.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        self.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear     
    }
}
```

and call that method in cellForRowAt